# Command line tool for reading .shp, .prj and converting to Google Maps lat lngs

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, web-mercator

I have a data file exported from an ARCGIS system (parcel data from local government).  Its a zip file containing 7 files:  f.dbf, f.prj, f.sbn, f.sbx, f.shp, f.shp.xml, f.shx.

I have a simple ruby script that uses the rgeo and rgeo/shapefile gem to read the .shp file and extract points.  The points don't look like lat, long eg.

```
936934.017177403 695547.1331697404
```

I would like to convert the points to lat longs that I can upload to google maps or similar.

I think the solution involves reading the .prj and .shp file, then telling the tool to project into EPSG:3867.

**Is there a simple script or commandline tool that handles conversions like this.**  eg:

```
convert f.shp f.prj -EPSG:3857 > new.shp
```

I would prefer to use a ruby / rgeo solution.  But anything unixy that can be scripted would work.

Comment: Is this a polygon or point layer?

Comment: There are 100K records, from what I can tell all MULTIPOLYGON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a trivial task with gdal:

```
 ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:3857 destination.shp source.shp
```

See http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html for more information.

There might be ruby bindings for this, I have no idea.

EPSG:3857 coordinates are not lat/long though, if you really need those, just use EPSG:4326.

Comment: Does ogr2ogr reads the .prj file implicitly?

Comment: The args are reversed, should be ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:3857 new.shp old.shp.

Comment: Oops, fixed. Yes, for GDAL/OGR the .prj file is just part of the Shapefile.